# Chrome extension how to insert a button to the page google calendar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to insert a button to the page google calendar, but it doesn't work..

manifest.json

```
    {  
  "name": " Demo ",
  "description": " demo ",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["https://www.google.com/calendar/*"],
                      "js": ["demo.js"]}
                      ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "icons" : {

    "128" : "icon.png"
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and content_scripts (demo.js):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                      var buttonOnSite = document.getElementById(":10.calendar-row"),
                      parent = buttonOnSite.parentElement,
                      next = buttonOnSite.nextSibling,
                      button = document.createElement("button"),
                      text = document.createTextNode("test");
                      button.appendChild(text);
                      if (next) parent.insertBefore(button, next);
                      else parent.appendChild(button);
});
```

Then I open the google calendar...I can not find my button.. `:10.calendar-row` is the ID of a element of the page calendar...

How I can insert a button to the page google calendar, Thank you !

I have a second question ,I can not debug, the button for debug is grey....Why?

[image]

Comment: dont debug the popup, you dont have one. debug the content script. read the official extensions dev guide which explains both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer for the seconde question, I know how to debug now, Could you help me for the first question ? How to insert a button to the pas google calendar? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you make sure that the URL of the google calender is correct and matches the pattern in manifest.json? (not something like https://calendar.google.com/calendar ?)

You can open Chrome Dev Tool and under Sources tab make sure you can find your content scripts. You can set a break point on your content script to see if it is actually running or not.

[Screenshot: Chrome Dev Tools > Sources > Content Scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PPdN.png)

Comment: I use `"https://calendar.google.com/calendar/*"` and it doesn't work, I have a second question ,I can not debug,  the button for debug is grey....Why? I have updated my question for debug